# How to select rows having empty values in all columns of the table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I do not want put all the columns like:

```
select * 
from tbl_AllTransactiondata 
where column1='' and  column2=''
```

Please help for short way because there are around 16 columns.

I need to get all the rows having empty data in all columns in SQL Server.

Comment: thnx I have used this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question.   I just learned something.   You can use CHECKSUM().  Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (
 col1 varchar(31) 
,col2 varchar(31)
);

INSERT INTO #tmp (col1,col2) VALUES ('','');

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM #tmp
WHERE CHECKSUM(*)=CHECKSUM('');

DROP TABLE #tmp;
```

This returns a result of 1.

So, if you do a SELECT from your table `WHERE CHECKSUM(*)=CHECKSUM('')` it will return all the rows where all columns are empty strings.

Comment: This is a superb solution and although `CHECKSUM()` was ringing bells, I have learned something also.

Comment: :)   This is when I love SO.. when it makes me try a weird experiment and it works.

Comment: @TabAlleman Great. Really.it is an superb solution***** ,,,,,,thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is using dynamic query, if you want to not hard-code the field names

```
DECLARE @sqlStr VARCHAR(max) = (
        SELECT stuff((
                    SELECT 'and ' + c.NAME + ' is null '
                    FROM sys.columns c
                    WHERE object_name(object_id) = 'yourtablename'
                    ORDER BY c.NAME
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                    ), 1, 3, '')
        )

SET @sqlStr = 'select * from ' + yourtablename + ' where ' + @sqlStr

PRINT @sqlStr

EXEC (@sqlStr)
```

*Please "Mark as Answer" if a post has answered the question*

Comment: It's not the ONLY possible solution.  ; )

Comment: I did not say this is the only possible solution. I said, "The only possible solution is using dynamic query" (w/o hard-coding the field names). If I'm not right, please give some hints.

Comment: Take a look at my CHECKSUM() experiment answer.

Comment: @TabAlleman, how can I use CHECKSUM() or any other way if I want to check if all fields are NULL? Any idea?

Comment: another interesting question.  I tried a couple of ideas, but it looks like CHECKSUM can't be used to determine if all fields are NULL.   My best idea is COALESCE(), but you'd have to type in all the field names.

Answer (score -1):

I tried  below query and it works fine

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_AllTransactiondata
WHERE COALESCE(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7,
               column8, column9, column10, column11, column12, column13,
               column14, column15, column16) =''
```

Comment: I don't think this will return a record where the first column has data and second column has empty string

Comment: @Prdp I want rows having empty value in all 16 columns

Comment: I think this query would return any row where the first column is an empty string, even if the other columns had data in them.   All COALESCE does for you is return the first column that isn't NULL.

Comment: @LaxminarayanCharan Tab Allerman is correct. You should be getting false positives using your `COALESCE(..., ...) = ''` criteria which isn't what I suggested. Use the `CHECKSUM()` solution posted by Tab instead.

Comment: @LaxminarayanCharan, you are using all columns, but looks like you were trying to avoid using column named as you have many column in your table. And, if you accept the answer, please mark it as answer to give some credit to who solved your problem.